# Как сделать текст из блока значением переменной?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько одноименных блоков, внутри которых есть значение "есть" и "нет", если значение равно "нет", то должен скрываться элемент "кнопка", так вот в коде ниже все работает, но если мы напишем вот так:

```
var thereis = $(this).find(".onechild").text();
```

то работать перестает, хотя значения переменной `thereis`  по-прежнему ничем не отличаются

```js
  $(".sibline").each(function(i) {
    var thereis = $(this).find(".onechild .val").text();

    if (thereis == 'Нет') {
      $(".sibline").find(".twochild").eq(i).css('display', 'none');
    }
  })
```

```css
.onechild {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #ccc;
}
.twochild {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #CDDC39;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sibline">
  <div class="onechild">
    <div class="val">Есть</div>
  </div>
  <div class="twochild">
    <div class="val">Кнопка</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sibline">
  <div class="onechild">
    <div class="val">Нет</div>
  </div>
  <div class="twochild">
    <div class="val">Кнопка</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sibline">
  <div class="onechild">
    <div class="val">Есть</div>
  </div>
  <div class="twochild">
    <div class="val">Кнопка</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sibline">
  <div class="onechild">
    <div class="val">Есть</div>
  </div>
  <div class="twochild">
    <div class="val">Кнопка</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При

```
var thereis = $(this).find(".onechild").text();
```

`thereis` не равен 'Есть', а равен слову с четырмья пробелами (табуляция) и переносом строки.

```
<div class="onechild">(перенос строки тут)
(4 пробела тут)<div class="val">Есть</div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как это проверили?  в консоль выводили или в тело страницы?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, По консолечке сразу видно, высокие поля для одного слова

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, всегда используйте функцию `String.prototype.trim` для подобных дел, но лучше реализовать это с помощью флага-атрибута типа: `data-visible=1`.

Comment: то есть значения "есть", "нет" поместить в атрибут? String.prototype.trim а вот это действительно полезно млао знаю еще)

Comment: @ЕвгенийШевцов, я бы сделал именно так. А Other имел ввиду найти альтернативу jquery методу text() на подобие trim